# Unable to locate an element through Selenium and WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

i am trying to click the save button. but i am not able to click it because before the button it has "::before".
i tried locating using cssSelector and xpath. but i am not able to locate it. can any one help me?

[image]

Comment: Show how you tried

Comment: what happens when you use driver.findElement(By.id("save")).click(); ?

Comment: Element not visible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element you are trying to locate is within a *Modal Dialog Box* so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the element to be clickable and you can use either of the following options :

- *cssSelector* :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.modal-footer button.btn.btn-default#save"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath* :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='modal-footer']//button[@class='btn btn-default' and @id='save']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: @Spartan Upvote the Answer if this/any answer was helpful to you for the future readers